# How to implement hive sql's map() equivalent in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Need help converting hive sql's map() function in BigQuery. I have example map()

Hive SQL:

```
with da as (select '1' key, 'one' value union all select '2' key, 'two' value union all select '2' key, 'tw0' value)
select map(key,value) as keyValue, keyValue from da;
```

Result:

```
keyvalue
{"1":"one"}
{"2":"two"}
{"2":"tw0"}
```

How to implement this map(k,v) and accessing value through corresponding key like map[key]?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic solution. There are 2 options you can use, depending on what you need for the final data

This is the data you are using as example:

```
    With da AS (
   (SELECT 1 AS key, 'one' AS value) UNION ALL
   (SELECT 2 AS key, 'two' AS value) UNION ALL
   (SELECT 2 AS key, 'tw0' AS value)
)
```

**First option** is to use the `concat` function. T**his returns the data just with the values**.

```
select concat('{"',key,'":"',value,'"}')  from da
```

[image]

You can access one key value. You can see this example.

```
select concat('{"',key,'":"',value,'"}')  from da where key='2'
```

[image]

**Second Option** is to use the `TO_JSON_STRING` function in BigQuery. You can see more documentation about this [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string). **This returns the data in JSON format**.

To display all the data you need to execute this query;

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS json_objects
FROM da AS t
```

[image]

If you want to access only one key, you need to filter like this example:

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) AS json_objects
FROM da AS t where t.key=2;
```

[image]